# Arraylist of String arrays not appending?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have created 3 arraylist which have a array of another type:

```
ArrayList<String[]> arrayListString = new ArrayList<String[]>();
ArrayList<int[]> arrayListInt = new ArrayList<int[]>();
ArrayList<double[]> arrayListDouble = new ArrayList<double[]>();
```

I am getting information from an api call, which I make from calling the below function. All I need to do is to append the arraylist so it can be redrawn with new item and the previous items to implement infinite scrolling. But now, when I make a second api call, I get the new items, I can even store them in new String arrays but I just can't append them to the arraylist. I have no idea why this is happening. The arraylist always contains the first api call string array and never gets updated. Can you please tell me where I am going wrong??

```
public void productListingApiCall(int i) {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(base_url).setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).build();
    final ProductListingApi productListingApi =
            restAdapter.create(ProductListingApi.class);
    productListingApi.getFeed(file, operation_condition, search_string_condition, minprice_condition, maxprice_condition, mincusratings_condition,
            maxcusratings_condition, discount_condition, catids_condition, brands_condition, affids_condition, start_row_condition, "5",
            orderby_condition, sortby_condition, new Callback<ProductListingPojo>() {

                @Override
                public void success(ProductListingPojo productListingPojo, Response response) {
                    final ProductListingPojo product = productListingPojo;
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            String[] t = Arrays.copyOf(product.getTitle(),
                                    product.getTitle().length);
                            int[] p = Arrays.copyOf(product.getSellingprice(),
                                    product.getSellingprice().length);
                            int[] m = Arrays.copyOf(product.getMrp(),
                                    product.getMrp().length);
                            int[] d = Arrays.copyOf(product.getDiscountpercent(),
                                    product.getDiscountpercent().length);
                            String[] i = Arrays.copyOf(product.getProductimageSmall1(),
                                    product.getProductimageSmall1().length);


                            String[] title = new String[5];
                            String[] image = new String[5];
                            int[] price = new int[5];
                            int[] mrp = new int[5];
                            int[] discount = new int[5];
                            title = t;
                            price = p;
                            mrp = m;
                            discount = d;
                            image = i;

                            arrayListString.add(title);
                            arrayListString.add(image);

                            arrayListInt.add(price);
                            arrayListInt.add(mrp);
                            arrayListInt.add(discount);

                            Log.e("t", Arrays.toString(t));
                            Log.e("pp", Arrays.toString(p));
                            Log.e("m", Arrays.toString(m));
                            Log.e("d", Arrays.toString(d));
                            Log.e("i", Arrays.toString(i));

                            Log.e("ttt", Arrays.toString(title));
                            Log.e("pppp", Arrays.toString(price));
                            Log.e("mmm", Arrays.toString(mrp));
                            Log.e("ddd", Arrays.toString(discount));
                            Log.e("iii", Arrays.toString(image));

                            Log.e("tttttt", Arrays.toString(arrayListString.get(0)));
                            Log.e("ppppppp", Arrays.toString(arrayListInt.get(0)));
                            Log.e("mmmmmm", Arrays.toString(arrayListInt.get(1)));
                            Log.e("dddddd", Arrays.toString(arrayListInt.get(2)));
                            Log.e("iiiiii", Arrays.toString(arrayListString.get(1)));
                        }
                    }).run();

                    setAdapter();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    tv_title_header.setText(error.getMessage());
                    Log.e("error", error.getMessage());
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: What is the output of the log statements ? I assume the first 5 logs (t,pp,m,d,i) will have the same output as (ttt,pppp,mmm,ddd,iii) as title=t,price=p,mrp=m,discount=d and image=i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code

```
Log.e("tttttt", Arrays.toString(arrayListString.get(0)));
Log.e("ppppppp", Arrays.toString(arrayListInt.get(0)));
Log.e("mmmmmm", Arrays.toString(arrayListInt.get(1)));
Log.e("dddddd", Arrays.toString(arrayListInt.get(2)));
Log.e("iiiiii", Arrays.toString(arrayListString.get(1)));
```

you are always looking at the first values which were added to the arrayLists. I suspect that the second time, if you would do

```
Log.e("tttttt", Arrays.toString(arrayListString.get(2)));
```

you will get the titles belonging to the 2nd api call. So you have to keep a counter somewhere which tells you if it is the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ... call to the API.

However, I suggest you store the data received from the API in a different way. Using `List`s is good, but you can make lists of every class you like, including your own. So if you create a `DataApi` class like this:

```
public class ApiData {
    public String[] title, image;
    int[] price, mrp, discount;
}
```

and replace the array lists you currently have with

```
private List<ApiData> arrayListData = new ArrayList<ApiData>();
```

then, you can store the data in it like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    ApiData data = new ApiData();
    data.title = Arrays.copyOf(product.getTitle(), product.getTitle().length);
    ...

    arrayListData.add(data);
```

When you need the titles of the first api call, you just use `arrayListData.get(0).title`.

(for bonus points, [encapsulate](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm) the public fields in the ApiData class).

Comment: Thank you so much, i only partially used your solution. I created a separate class which stores single value of string and ints. Then i iterate and add it to the class as well as the arraylist. It works. But i do have another question. When i try the infinite scrolling, the new items do load but the screen is refreshed to the top. what can i do to stop this?

Comment: By the way i am using this link for infinite scrolling: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews